# I need to get the index of specified row, say first rows index from pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have pandas Series from excel sheet, where each row may contain one or more of the following data from list (dict = ['Management', 'Sales', 'Executive', 'Communication', 'Finance', 'IT / Engineering', 'Legal', 'Marketing', 'Support']), but may even not contain.
I'm iterating it via this code, which returns list of indexes for my future exploration:

```
dict = ['Management', 'Sales', 'Executive', 'Communication', 'Finance', 'IT / Engineering', 'Legal', 'Marketing', 'Support']
series = src_df['Department'].tolist()
if len(series)>0:
    listindexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(series) if x in dict]
    for item in dict:
        for num in listindexes:
            if item == series[num]:
                newlist.append(item)
    return newlist
```

After iteration, if no one from list items are not in Series, I want to take first(or second, or other) rows position index number, but I dont know whether the cell is empty, or not.
How to set to the variable the INDEX of the first position, for future calling?

Comment: what is `dict`?

Comment: dict = ['Management', 'Sales', 'Executive', 'Communication', 'Finance', 'IT / Engineering', 'Legal', 'Marketing', 'Support'] 
I mentioned it above in the text

Comment: don't use variable dict. it is python object. Also your variable, naming is conflicting with data type. Its list but your are naming it as dict.

Comment: In my code I used other variable name. Only here I named variable dist